# dpkg-gencontrol: warning: can't parse dependency cpp_common

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I was trying to generate .deb from the roscpp_traits package on a Raspberry pi 3B+ using bloom (python-bloom/stretch,now 0.8.0-1 all), I got the following error

```
...
dh binary -v --buildsystem=cmake
   dh_gencontrol -O-v -O--buildsystem=cmake
       dpkg-gencontrol -pros-kinetic-roscpp-traits -ldebian/changelog -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits.substvars -Pdebian/ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits
dpkg-gencontrol: warning:     debian/changelog(l5): found trailer where expected start of change data
LINE:  -- Dirk Thomas <dthomas@osrfoundation.org>  Thu, 01 Feb 2018 13:00:00 -0000
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits: unknown substitution variable 
${shlibs:Depends}
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: can't parse dependency cpp_common
dpkg-gencontrol: error: error occurred while parsing Depends field: , , boost, catkin, cpp_common, libconsole-bridge-dev
dh_gencontrol: dpkg-gencontrol -pros-kinetic-roscpp-traits -ldebian/changelog -Tdebian/ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits.substvars -
Pdebian/ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits returned exit code 255
debian/rules:22: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
```

Apparently, ${shlibs:Depends} and ${misc:Depends} variables were not properly populated.

What drives me puzzled is on the same machine I can generate .deb package for rostime. Similar to roscpp_traits, rostime also lists cpp_common as a run_depend.

I had a .yaml file and for dependencies with entries like:

```
rostime:
    debian:
      stretch: [cpp_common]
```

and

```
roscpp_traits:
  debian:
    stretch: [rostime, cpp_common]
```

It is cached by rosdep by entry in the **/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list**

```
yaml file:///home/pi/raspi_rosdep.yaml kinetic stretch debian
```

Can somebody help or point me to where I should look at.

Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328694/dpkg-gencontrol:-warning:-can%27t-parse-dependency-cpp_common/) by [vunguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/41752/vunguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. It turned out that the dependency entries of the local .yaml was wrong. Dashes ('-') should had been used instead of underscore ('_').

---

Originally posted by [vunguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/41752/vunguyen/) with karma: 31 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0